# How To Calculate Android App Runtime ~Android

Tags: java, android, runtime

I need to calculate my Android App runtime in a day. Is there a way to do this?

For example:

If I start(open) my app at Sunday 07:00AM, and I close my app at Sunday 07:15AM, it will get 15 minutes of runtime. And If I open again my app at Sunday 11:50PM and I close my App at Monday 00:20AM in the very next day, It will get 25 minutes of runtime on Sunday and 20 minutes of runtime on Monday.

Is there a practical way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Sure there is a way. What is holding you back from trying?

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by saving the current dateTime to your sharedpreferences in your onResume.

In your onPause I would get the saved startTime from your preferences and calculate the difference with the current time. Next, clear the saved starttime and update your database with the time the user was active this day.